# Will a light bulb work the same on a car battery?

Tags: resistance, current-measurement

So I have an incandescent light bulb that is rated for 100W at a voltage of 220V. So, I calculated that the resistance of the bulb is 484Ω.

I wanted to connect it to a car battery (24V). I know most incandescent light bulbs work with both AC and DC so this shouldn't be a problem. I calculated that at 24V, the current will be about 50mA. Multiplying, I got that the power from the battery would be 1.2W, which is not enough for it to light up.

I still connected it and the bulb got destroyed (filament broken), so the current must have been very high. Can anybody help me understand what happened?

Comment: What do you mean by "popped"?

Comment: @Andyaka my bad, I meant to say the filament broke

Comment: picture of bulb, showing the rating?

Comment: Car batteries are 12 volts btw.

Comment: Unless it was an EV or a large truck (or an antique vehicle) modern car batteries tend to be 12V.

Comment: Get a DMM and verify your incorrect assumptions. Hot tungsten has a huge PTC effect 1:10 on resistance

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Thank you, that must be it!

Comment: More likely, vibration broke the filament. Even at 1/10 the hot resistance, that lamp should not have gotten warm.

Comment: 6W surge is nothing compare to expect 10x 1kW surge.   What is history of your failure?

Answer (score 1):

484 Ω is the correct for R = 220²/100W when hot ~ 2906'K  but at room temp. = 300'K,  R= 24.2 Ω  .

Thus when 12V is applied I ~ 12V/24Ω = 500mA , P= 6W, the filament raises its temp to 348'K R = 77Ω P= 1.87W and the current reduces to 156 mA in 1 second.

Did any parameter exceed spec?

- Most likely mechanical shock.

Better question : What is the worst-case surge power at 220Vrms=311Vp if turned on exactly at peak Vac?
: Answer = 1288 W :

So normal worst-case  R ratio was actually 20 = 484 Ω/ 24.2 Ω , but if AC turned on at 0 deg phase the peak power turns out to be much less and rapid rise in R before the peak voltage. In a simulation the peak surge power was only 1/2 of the worst-case at 681 W, based on an assumed thermal rise time of 400 ms.  So the mean surge power ratio is phase-dependent.  Thus we tend to use a mean 10:1 surge power and resistance ratio.

This also explains why so many old bulbs failed during power on by induction as the filament force is proportional to the oscillating current.

[Simulation](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000024999999999999998%200.26073472713092677%2041%205%2050%0A181%20208%20112%20208%20192%200%20580.4420037719653%20100%20220%200.4%200.4%0Av%20144%20384%20144%20304%200%200%2040%2012%200%200%200.5%0Av%20144%20192%20144%20112%200%201%2050%20311.1269837220809%200%200%200.5%0Aw%20144%20112%20208%20112%202%0Aw%20144%20192%20208%20192%200%0Aw%20208%20384%20144%20384%200%0A403%2016%2064%20144%20128%200%202_64_7_4354_320_0.1_0_1_1280%0Ag%20208%20192%20208%20208%200%0Aw%20144%20304%20208%20304%202%0A181%20208%20304%20208%20384%200%20304.6052044876844%20100%20220%200.4%200.4%0Ag%20208%20384%20208%20400%200%0A403%20272%20320%20400%20384%200%209_64_7_20738_5_0.1_0_1_10%0A403%2016%20176%20144%20240%200%200_64_0_4354_320_0.1_0_2_0_3%0A403%20288%20112%20416%20176%200%200_64_7_21250_320_0.1_0_1_1280%0Ao%200%20128%200%204865%2020%203.2%200%202%200%203%0A)